# DeskTime Application Not Working Very Well in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

I have installed the DeskTime application on the X and starting on that but when I check the Data on the DeskTime it is not updated. I have checked with the (EFFECTIVENESS and PRODUCTIVITY) it is not updated. But When I checked with Other OS like Mac or Ubuntu it is updating. So it is depending on other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment DeskTime support only clean Ubuntu LTS versions 16.04 or higher. Ubuntu X and other different desktop environments need to use older DeskTime app. Here is more: https://desktime.com/faq/getting-started/what-systems-does-desktime-support

Comment: Thanks for the help